# "Embed" with just ordinary YouTube url

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, youtube

I was wondering if its possible to implement YouTube videos in html - the catch is that I want to do it without having to click "share" and "embed" on YouTube to get the link. Instead, I want it so that I can just copy the url.

For example, instead of this link https://www.youtube.com/embed/09m0B8RRiEE,

I want to have this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09m0B8RRiEE

The purpose is so that I can have a platform where users can just copy paste seamlessly, without dealing with unnecessary extra clicks - Like you can sorta do on Facebook.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09m0B8RRiEE has `x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN` in its header. So you cannot just simply embed it within your websites via iframes.

Instead of embed `/watch?v=` URLs, you can either transform it to `/embed/` using JavaScript before setting as the src of an iframe, or make a server (as a proxy) to redirect the URL manually.

Update: A redirect demo:

HTML (use the `data` attribute):

`<iframe data-src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09m0B8RRiEE" />`

JS (jQuery):

```
$('iframe').each(function () {
  let originalSrc = $(this).data('src')
  let src = originalSrc.replace('/watch?v=', '/embed/')
  $(this).attr('src', src)
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know how to do it via javascript? It's probably the best way..

Comment: @user9121872 just added a demo using jQuery =)